# RESTful Java service not serializing ArrayList

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jax-ws, javax.ws.rs

Here is a sample code of my `GET` method that should return `xml` serialized version of `ConfigurationProperty` as a response.

It serializes the `ConfigurationProperty` model in most of the times, except when the `value` is set to an `ArrayList`.

What may be the cause and how should I fix it, when the serialization is done using `javax.ws.rs.Produces`?

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public ConfigurationProperty getConfigurationProperty(@PathParam("id") Id id)
{
    ConfigurationProperty cp = service.get(ConfigurationProperty.class, id);
    return checked(cp);
}
```

Content of `cp`:

```
cp  DefaultConfigurationProperty  (id=293)  
    __scsIsPartialObject    false   
    __scsTransientServiceFields HashMap<K,V>  (id=312)  
    createdBy   "migration" (id=313)    
    createdOn   Date  (id=314)  
    id  Id  (id=315)    
    key "catalog/cron/product_status_export/try_languages" (id=316) 
    merchantIds null    
    modifiedBy  null    
    modifiedOn  null    
    requestContextIds   null    
    storeIds    null    
    value   ArrayList<E>  (id=317)  
        elementData Object[10]  (id=326)    
            [0] MongoValue  (id=13837)  
                object  "de" (id=13846) 
            [1] MongoValue  (id=13838)  
                object  "en" (id=13853) 
            [2] MongoValue  (id=13839)  
                object  "global" (id=13860) 
        modCount    3   
        size    3   
    version null
```

`MongoValue.java`:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.app.core.service.api.Value;
import com.app.core.type.TypeConverter;

public final class MongoValue implements Value
{
    Object object = null;

    public MongoValue(Object object)
    {
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public String getString()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asString(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getInteger()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asInteger(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Long getLong()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asLong(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Double getDouble()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asDouble(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Float getFloat()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asFloat(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Short getShort()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asShort(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getBoolean()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asBoolean(object);
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asBigDecimal(object);
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger getBigInteger()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asBigInteger(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Character getChar()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asCharacter(object);
    }

    @Override
    public <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnum(Class<E> enumType)
    {
        return TypeConverter.asEnum(enumType, object);
    }

    @Override
    public UUID getUUID()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asUUID(object);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAscii()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asASCII(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Date getDate()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asDate(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRaw()
    {
        return TypeConverter.asRaw(object);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.valueOf(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: `MongoValue` seems to be causing this.

Comment: I added `@XmlRootElement()` as you said with empty brackets and it didn't work.

Comment: No exception related to this is shown in my log. I only see exception response in browser: `500 Internal Server Error`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to add a custom serializer for the value field of DefaultConfigurationProperty. You should be able to accomplish this with a Jackson custom serializer[1].

[1] http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers